# Issue - Hover of Submenu CSS

Tags: html, css, submenu

**HTML**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='active'>
            <a href="Index.aspx">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="AboutUs.aspx">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
        <li class='has-sub '>
            <a href="Products.aspx">PRODUCTS</a>
            <ul>
                <li class='has-sub '>
                   <a href='#'>Product 1</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                       <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li class='has-sub '>
                    <a href='#'>Product 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#'>Sub Item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Services.aspx">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Enquiry.aspx">ENQUIRY</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="ContactUs.aspx">CONTACT US</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ5Cp/24/)

As you can see the fiddle the submenu of the list item PRODUCT collapses in this.. i am working on this for more than an hour, can you help where i am doing mistake and need clear explanation too..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, @vals and @shomz are half correct.

You do need to add `height:100%;` to `#cssmenu ul ul`

BUT, to fix the Product 1 and Product 2 sub menu overlapping, you need to change:

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: -99.5%;
}
```

TO:

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

And @shomz is right, there is a lot of unnecessary styling going on here.

For example, you define `#cssmenu ul ul ul` TWICE:

ONCE as:

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
}
```

and a second time as:

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    border-top: 0 none;
}
```

You need to go back and combine instances of duplication like this because if you leave the first one that defines `top` and `left`, then in the one with `border` you add `top:0;` and `left: 100%;`, things will not work I describe.

Comment: the changes what you said doesn't shows up the submenu :(

Comment: Interesting.  This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SQ5Cp/30/) seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Read the last part of my post about duplicate rule definitions.  And I totally dig your color choices!

Answer (score 1):

The 100% height of `#cssmenu ul li` is causing it to overlap. It takes the height of the parent ul element, which is 0.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/SQ5Cp/26/

This fixes the issue, but you should probably consider rewriting some parts of it in the future (like removing the absolute positioning of the child ul elements, etc).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, now the left submenu is collapsing, ill look into it..!!

Answer (score 1):

Just a little behind Shomz answer ...

However, I would solve it this way (adding height 100% to ul of second level):

```
#cssmenu ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   /* added */
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/SQ5Cp/27/)

Change also this for the submenu

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/SQ5Cp/32/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, now the left submenu is collapsing, ill look into it..!! Thanks once again..!!

Comment: the second fiddle works as expected but @ddenhartog has given me the answer already and thank you for your valuable time..!!

Comment: I was just answering your comment and didn't see it :-)